Add or replace nodes and attributesTransform Xml via xsl, and present the transformed xml in an html table throught the transforming xsl
I have to transform a xml file to a html, adding (or replacing)
particular nodes and attributes of the xml file, through the code of
xsl. The problem is that:
(a) the whole replaced node is rendered
together with its replaced attributes, and
(b) the original node is also
rendered.
The output of my xsl is:
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p code="cc" price="33">C</p>
<p>3</p>

And the desired output must be:
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>33</p>

The xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Features>
  <Feature code="a" price = "1"></Feature>
  <Feature code="b" price = "2"></Feature>
  <Feature code="c" price = "3"></Feature>
</Features>

The xsl:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Feature[@code='c']">  
  <p code="cc" price="33">C</p>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  </xsl:template>
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Feature"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Feature">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@price"/>
  </xsl:template>
 
  <xsl:template match="@price">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/> </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Please edit your question and add the exact output you expect to get (as HTML code, if you expect an HTML result).

You can get the exact result you show very simply using only:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />

 <xsl:template match="Feature">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="@price" />
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Feature[@code='c']">
    <p>33</p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

But you say you want the result to be an HTML file. So maybe you should do:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Features">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Feature">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="@price" />
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Feature[@code='c']">
    <p>33</p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

to get a valid HTML result like:
<html>
   <body>
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>33</p>
   </body>
</html>


Thanks but its not the idea. The goal is my further procedure with many 33 (as for example price="33", price="331", price="332" etc). Through my code its only the new transformed nodes() which can been extracted, but it is impossible to extract my required new constructed attributes. Any idea ?

Sorry, I have no clue what you refer to. Please add a detailed  explanation of the required logic to your question.
